# Can we disable the feature of multiple tabs from IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer

Can we disable the feature of opening multiple tabs in IE7 or above versions of Internet Explorer?
I want that in one window of IE7 or above only one tab should remain active...

Comment: How are you trying to accomplish this? As someone running a website, or someone who's got administrative rights on the machines/domain that this IE7 copy is running inside of? Via GPO you could probably finagle something, as a website operator, no way.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish this via some code which even I dont know right now as I have searched it everywhere but I found no idea ho to implement it..:-(

Comment: what kind of code? what language? where will this code run?

Comment: maybe some javascript code....I want to run this code on IIS where my website is hosted

Comment: then there is very little you can do to affect a user's browser. at most you can try to detect if a new window/tab is opened, but you can **NOT** stop the user from doing so.

Comment: Yes I reached till this point but now I am not finding any way to stop the user. I guess Microsoft does not allow this feature to be disabled ;)

Comment: it's not microsoft, it's all browsers. imagine how fun the web would be if advertisers could keep you from closing a window, opening a new one, etc... It's simple basic browser security.

Comment: I fully agree with you Marc but I have to search the entire web to convince my supervisor.....:)

Comment: At risk of this comment being flagged, your supervisor is an idiot. See the link @Karan posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your moronic supervisor thinks he's in charge of [the coolest most amazing site ever written in the history of mankind](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030903-00/?p=42673) (paraphrasing Mr. Chen), which is just so awesome that it can force its users' browsers/PCs to behave just the way *it* wants.

BTW, why exactly does he want to implement this? What will happen if multiple tabs are opened? Sounds like the webapp design itself is broken, and he's attempting to cover it up by forcing users to interact with the site in a pre-determined constrained manner.

Comment: I can't think of anything that'd break with multiple tabs that wouldn't break with multiple windows too.

Comment: @Wyzard: Hmm, you're right. Which makes me even more mystified regarding the exact reason for this sort of bizarre requirement.